# Code different locally and on browser

Tags: laravel, google-chrome, laravel-5, amazon-ec2

I am using laravel with EC2 amazon webserver running on ubuntu, and the problem is when I run the website on a browser the code is different. As an example please see images below.

I have tried to clear views, clear-compiled, clear cache, disable cache in browser as well as delete DNS setting in google chrome however I still have the same problem.

Code on "local file"
[image]

Code on browser
[image]

On localhost, if I update the file, code updates straight away but on the server it doesn't. Someone can help?

Comment: Same on others browsers ? (Firefox, etc.)

Comment: Are you using cache busting for your CSS files? If using Laravel mix to compile, you can build in versioning. If not, just tack on a version number at the end of your CSS path (i.e.: ?v=1)